# df.head() don't print column and row

Tags: python, deep-learning

i try convert image to vector (feature extraction) using convolutional layer but it not work

```
def get_extract_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1))) 
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1))) 
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()) 
    
    return model
    
Model = get_extract_model()
Model.summary()
```

```
# convert images to vectors and extract features

def feature_extraction(data):
    vectors = []
    for i in data :
        img = i.reshape(1,28,28,1)
        vector = Model.predict(img)[0]
        vectors.append(vector)
    return vectors
```

```
vector_top = feature_extraction(df['tshirt_top'])
vector_trouser = feature_extraction(df['trouser'])
vector_pullover = feature_extraction(df['pullover'])
vector_dress = feature_extraction(df['dress'])
vector_coat = feature_extraction(df['coat'])
vector_sandal = feature_extraction(df['sandal'])
vector_shirt = feature_extraction(df['shirt'])
vector_sneaker = feature_extraction(df['sneaker'])
vector_bag = feature_extraction(df['bag'])
vector_ankle_boot = feature_extraction(df['ankle_boot'])

# Save vectors to Pandas
df_vector = pd.DataFrame({'tshirt_top': vector_top, 'trouser': vector_trouser, 'pullover': vector_pullover,
                          'dress': vector_dress, 'coat': vector_coat, 'sandal': vector_sandal, 
                          'shirt': vector_shirt, 'sneaker': vector_sneaker, 'bag': vector_bag, 
                          'ankle_boot': vector_ankle_boot})
df_vector.head()
```

but it print:

[image]

I tried to fix the model but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The crux of this question ***df.head() don't print column and row*** is not about fixing the model (which is runable according to your attached image), but about correctly hashing the Fashion MNIST dataset into ten categories (tshirt_top, trouser, etc.) before dumping it to pd.DataFrame.

I prefer using `dict()` in this case.

```
df = {'tshirt_top': x_train[y_train==0], 'trouser': x_train[y_train==1]}
```

and the output of `df_vector.head()` in csv format and [its pretty screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXucP.jpg).

| index | tshirt_top | trouser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [0. 0. 0. ... 0.0122097 0.00523345 0. ] | [0.00150987 0.00130126 0. ... 0.00465766 0.00190011 0. ] |
| 1 | [1.0521491e-03 2.9476351e-04 0.0000000e+00 ... 1.2752928e-03 5.0676049e-04 4.4454282e-06] | [0.00124143 0.00132154 0. ... 0. 0.00336032 0. ] |
| 2 | [0. 0.00070373 0. ... 0.00372491 0.00162563 0. ] | [0.00126607 0.00114025 0. ... 0.00232333 0.00150575 0. ] |
| 3 | [0. 0.00548789 0. ... 0.00764147 0.00447769 0. ] | [6.7898305e-05 1.4743840e-04 0.0000000e+00 ... 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00] |
| 4 | [0. 0.00347646 0. ... 0.00466574 0.00209899 0. ] | [0.00047809 0.0011074 0. ... 0.00271977 0.0026074 0. ] |